# SAS combine 3 datasets and assign its corresponding dataset name

Tags: sas

I have 3 dataset as shown:

```
data dataA;
    input id;
    datalines;
1001
1002
1003
;
run;

data dataB;
    input id;
    datalines;
1001
1002
1003
;
run;

data dataC;
    input id;
    datalines;
1001
1002
1003
;
run;
```

i would like to have output:

```
1001 dataA
1002 dataA
1003 dataA
1001 dataB
1002 dataB
1003 dataB
1001 dataC
1002 dataC
1003 dataC
```

I know how to combine three data sets using

```
data datacombine;
  set dataA dataB dataC;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the most standard way of doing it:

```
data datacombine;
   set dataA(in=A) dataB(in=B) dataC(in=C);
   if      A then origin = "dataA";
   else if B then origin = "dataB";
   else if C then origin = "dataC";
run;
```

The [in= dataset option](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ledsoptsref/67381/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1p1o2dsuc465nn198ovwdrj9mvy.htm) sets a flag if the row originated from the corresponding input dataset.

Answer (score 7):

If you have SAS 9.2 or newer then you could use the `INDSNAME` option http://support.sas.com/kb/34/513.html

```
data datacombine;
format dsname datasetname $25.; 
  set dataA dataB dataC indsname=dsname;
  datasetname=dsname;
run;
```

Comment: Joe has beautifully explained it alrady in some other post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144138/sas-concatenate-different-datasets-while-keeping-the-individual-data-table-name/12161432#12161432 
this marks your question as duplicate!!

Comment: Good point, I've closed as duplicate - feel free to flag to close as well in the future (I think you can do that at your rep level?).